# use function inside of loop which returns vector

Tags: c++, function, stdvector

I have a function `myfun` which will return a vector.

```
vector<double> myfun(const size_t k, const size_t i){
    vector<double> v(k);
    // do some computation with remaining arguments
    return v;
}
```

Then, I will use it in the loop to update `v` and use `v` to get some result.

```
int main(){
    size_t N = 100; // iteration size
    size_t n = 10; // size of v
    vector<double> result(N);
    vector<double> v(n);
    for(size_t i = 0; i<N; i++){
        v = myfun(n,i); // compute for each iteration
        result[i] = compute_some_value(v);
    }
}
```

So, my question is:

- Does `v` actually allocated inside of `myfun` every time it is called?
- If it does, what happens to old `v`?
- Also, is it better to use just use address like `void myfun(some_args, vector<double> &v)` for output argument `v`?

Answer (score 1):

> Does v actually allocated inside of myfun every time it is called?

Yes

> If it does, what happens to old v?

It gets overwritten.

> Also, is it better to use just use address like void myfun(some_args, vector &v) for output argument v?

Yes, it's better to pass vector by reference depending on your operations.

You could do it this way

```
double compute_some_value(vector<double> & v, const size_t i) {
    v.clear();    // use if required
    // do some computation with remaining arguments and return
}

int main() {
    size_t N = 100; // iteration size
    size_t n = 10; // size of v
    vector<double> result(N), v(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        result[i] = compute_some_value(v, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does v actually allocated inside of myfun every time it is called?

Yes

> If it does, what happens to old v?

When v gets out of scope the destructor is called and the object gets destruct. This is why you don't really have to call destructor of a class explicitly.

> Also, is it better to use just use address like void myfun(some_args,
>   vector &v) for output argument v?

It really depends on your use case. If it concerns with memory issues, its better to pass the reference.